# Can Visual Studio CPU sampling help identify database vs. method execution time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, profiling

In Java webapps, I often do CPU sampling through jvisualvm to distinguish database bottlenecks from other processing in the application.  Long-running database queries will show up as time spent within the JDBC driver's classes and methods.

It looks like ASP.NET tooling and database drivers don't work the same way.  If I profile with CPU sampling, I don't see any of the time spent in methods while waiting for I/O.  If I want to compare database and application bottlenecks side-by-side, I need to use instrumentation.

In other words, CPU samples are not an approximation -- they are fundamentally a different metric.

Is this because of a difference in how the CPU sampling process works in Java vs. the CLR, or is it a difference in how the database drivers work?  Or a difference in how the CLR vs. JVM treat time spent waiting for I/O?

Comment: CPU samplers ignore I/O, by definition. They are based on the assumption that you want visibility into actual time spent executing instructions in your process. That does not include I/O, sleep, locking, any sort of system wait.

Comment: That makes sense.  What I'm not understanding is why, in the Java world, CPU sampling *does* seem to turn up DB issues.

Comment: The DB also spends some CPU time. If it spends it in your thread it will be seen. If it runs on a separate thread but the profiler includes that thread, then you will also see it. Either way, time spend in actual I/O reads and writes, either to disc or to other processes, will not appear in CPU time. (Even though a disk controller is just a different CPU.)